# TypeScript error in passing props to child component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building a expense tracker app using react + typescript

expense_type.ts

```
    export  type IState = {
    id : number,
    text : string,
    amount : number

}

export type IinitialStateType =  {
    transactions : IState[]
}

export type IActions =  {
    type : string,
    payload : any
}

export type contextProps = {
    transactions : IState[];
    addTransaction: (trans: IState) => void;
    deleteTransaction: (id: number) => void;
}
```

Then I have used API Context and reducer and initialize my initial states in Global State file

GlobalState.tsx

```
import React , {createContext,useReducer} from 'react'
import {IinitialStateType,contextProps} from '../Types/expense_type'
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'

const initailState : IinitialStateType = {
    transactions : [
          { id: 1, text: 'Flower', amount: -20 },
          { id: 2, text: 'Salary', amount: 300 },
          { id: 3, text: 'Book', amount: -10 },
          { id: 4, text: 'Camera', amount: 150 }
    ]
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext<Partial<contextProps>>({})

export const GlobalProvider : React.FC = ({children}) : JSX.Element => {

    const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer,initailState)
    
    return(
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{
            transactions : state.transactions
        }}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Then I have used context in TransactionList.tsx component and map all the initial state values and pass those values to child component Transaction.tsx where those values are receiving

TransactionList.tsx

```
import React ,{useContext}from 'react'
import {GlobalContext} from './../Context/GlobalState'
import {contextProps,IinitialStateType,IState} from '../Types/expense_type'
import {Transaction} from './Transaction'

export const TransactionList : React.FC = () : JSX.Element => {

    const {transactions} : any = useContext(GlobalContext)
    return (
        <>   
            <h3>History</h3>
            <ul className="list">
                { 
                    transactions.map( (transaction : IState , index : number)  => 
                        (<Transaction key={index} transaction={transaction} />
                    )) 
                 }
            </ul>
        
        </>
    )
}
```

Transaction.tsx

```
    import React from 'react'
    import {IinitialStateType} from '../Types/expense_type'
    export const Transaction : React.FC<IinitialStateType>= (props : any) : JSX.Element => {

    let sign : string = props.transaction.amount > 0 ? '+' : '-'

    return (
        <>
            <li className={props.transaction.ammount < 0 ? "minus" : "plus"}>
                {props.transaction.text}{" "}
                <span>
                    {sign}${Math.abs(props.transaction.ammount)}
                </span>
                <button
                    className="btn-delete"
                >
                    x
                </button>
            </li>
        </>
    )
}
```

But while compiling it gives error in TransactionList.tsx file

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/Abdul Rehman Aziz/Desktop/New folder/expense-tracker-ts/src/Components/TransactionList.tsx(14,88): Type '{ key: number; transaction: IState; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IState & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'transaction' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IState & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322

    12 |             <h3>History</h3>
    13 |             <ul className="list">
  > 14 |                  { transactions.map( transaction => (<Transaction key={transaction.id} transaction={transaction} />)) }
       |                                                                                        ^
    15 |             </ul>
    16 |         </>
    17 |         </>
```

Comment: One comment that I think it is useful for you is to avoid using index as key of component as you are doing in TransactionList, since that is the default behaviour and if you are using it to display a list that can be mutated you will run into issues. Your issue is that you are passing a prop called Transaction that does not exist on type IinitialStateType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the type of Props for React.FC, not state. Like this:

```
export const Transaction: React.FC<{ transaction: IState }> = (
  props: any
```

I have also made a working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sanderson-e6zlm?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Your Transaction component is expecting props of type IinitialStateType and as per your definition of that type it does not has a property called transaction and as well it does not receive one item but an array. If you change the Type of your props in the Transaction component to something like

```
export const Transaction : React.FC<IState>= (props : any) : JSX.Element => {
...
}
```

it should help.